# Mysql gem install query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When installing the Mysql gem and I have RVM installed, do I install with sudo gem install mysql or do I do it through the rvm some how??

many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You just want to switch into your RVM profile and then do a `gem install mysql`. Normally you don't want to use the `sudo` when install gems into an RVM profile.

Answer (score 0):

type rvm list then you'll see which ruby version is active. running gem install will install the gem for that verison of ruby.